# Scala worksheet with http client dispatch library

Tags: scala, xml-parsing, httpclient, scala-2.10

I'm working on learning scala and I've run into a bit of a roadblock when it comes to accessing a ReST api.

Here are the dependencies for the project currently:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"
)
```

Here's the code I'm currently working with in a scala worksheet.

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._

val request = url(s"http://freegeoip.net/xml/www.google.com")


val busTime = Http( request <<? Map("key"->apiKey) OK as.xml.Elem)


def extractTime(xml: scala.xml.Elem) =
    for {
        response <- xml \\ "Response"
    } yield xml

busTime()
```

However, when I try to parse the xml expression in the way that was listed in a book I have on scala I get the following exception and I can't figure out why.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.Range.validateRangeBoundaries(Lscala/Function1;)Z
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.done(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:321)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.markAsDone(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:1427)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.finishUpdate(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:1443)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.access$2500(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:149)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$HttpProtocol.handle(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:2195)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.messageReceived(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:1150)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:66)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:560)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:787)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:138)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:560)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(experiment.sc8852822906338575612.tmp:787)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.Range.validateRangeBoundaries(Lscala/Function1;)Z
    at scala.xml.parsing.FactoryAdapter.startElement(FactoryAdapter.scala:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:745)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1277)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3065)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.loadXML(XMLLoader.scala:40)
    at scala.xml.XML$$anon$1.loadXML(XML.scala:68)
    at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.loadString(XMLLoader.scala:59)
    at scala.xml.XML$$anon$1.loadString(XML.scala:68)
    at dispatch.as.xml.Elem$.apply(elem.scala:8)
    at dispatch.as.xml.Elem$.apply(elem.scala:6)
```

The stranger part is when I parse the response as just a String it shows up fine with valid xml.  Although since this is just a string that's not what I want and it'd be great to be able to use the above feature.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

### Update

Per the comment I thought to try it in just the sbt repl which resulted as follows:

```
scala> val request = url(s"http://freegeoip.net/xml/www.google.com")
request: dispatch.Req = Req(<function1>)

scala> var response = Http( request OK as.xml.Elem)
response: dispatch.Future[scala.xml.Elem] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7fd2e7a

scala> response()
res2: scala.xml.Elem =
<Response>
    <Ip>173.194.64.106</Ip>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <RegionCode>CA</RegionCode>
    <RegionName>California</RegionName>
    <City>Mountain View</City>
    <ZipCode>94043</ZipCode>
    <Latitude>37.4192</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-122.0574</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>807</MetroCode>
    <AreaCode>650</AreaCode>
</Response>

scala> def extractTime(xml: scala.xml.Elem) =
     |     for {
     |         response <- xml \\ "Response"
     |     } yield xml
extractTime: (xml: scala.xml.Elem)scala.xml.NodeSeq

scala> extractTime(response())
res3: scala.xml.NodeSeq =
NodeSeq(<Response>
    <Ip>173.194.64.106</Ip>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <RegionCode>CA</RegionCode>
    <RegionName>California</RegionName>
    <City>Mountain View</City>
    <ZipCode>94043</ZipCode>
    <Latitude>37.4192</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-122.0574</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>807</MetroCode>
    <AreaCode>650</AreaCode>
</Response>)
```

So now my new question is why does this set of commands work in the repl but not in the worksheet?

Comment: This is a Scala Worksheet issue, and tagging it as such would make it more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a tag available for scala-worksheet and I don't have enough rep to create one. Thanks for the recommendation though I changed the post title

Comment: "Xerces hell" is a thing, and the issue is just that you've got different versions on the classpath via Worksheet and Dispatch. Adding an exclusion for the Dispatch one should fix the issue.

Comment: @TravisBrown I've heard of "xerces hell" however I'm not too familiar with the scala build process/environment yet.  Currently I'm using the scala/sbt plugins in intellij.  Any ideas as to where I should look for the duplicate dependency?